# Zookeeeper Invalid Config with [myid:]

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to start Kafka, but my Zookeeper id is not displayed rather it only shows `[myid:]`

I tried changing the port numbers yet I still have the same problem. find the attached copy of the error message.

I tried changing the file name ,and  port number and removing extra spaces in server properties yet I couldn't run my Kafka Cluster.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFVRy.png)

Comment: The error you're sharing is on zookeeper server and not kafka server, could you share your config file please ? because I think that you tell zookeeper that there is an other instance of zookeeper that it couldn't be reached.

Comment: Removing Kafka tag. Your error is only from Zookeeper. Read the Kafka quickstart guide, and you can see that Zookeeper is no longer required